# Can a Word 2010 document be used to gather information and create documents based on the input?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word-2010, vba, forms

Here is the problem I am trying to solve, and my question is, "Can this be done in MS Word 2010?"

1. MS Word 2010 form is given to user
2. User returns form to me, completely filled out
3. Based on the information collected, 3 different documents are automatically generated via me clicking a button on the form.

The documents that management wants me to generate are:

1. A proposal, which basically amounts to a giant form letter where a bunch of text will always be the same, and certain sentences/paragraphs/tables will need to be altered based on the response provided by the user. (For example, if the user indicates "Apples" and "Red" in their respective fields, then a specific sentence in the proposal might change from "It's unknown whether Mike likes apples." to "Mike indicated he likes Apples, specifically red ones." Basically I'm looking for a way to create some dynamic paragraphs based on the answers the user provides.
2. An Excel spreadsheet, with certain cells populated by the content found in the Word form
3. A form letter, which again picks and pulls certain pieces of content from the original form the the user filled out.

I'm familiar with VBA but less familiar with using data gathered to generate other forms.

Comment: I posted this on StackOverflow but it was advised I move it over to superuser.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to do this with a Word document? A simple web form would be much much easier.

Comment: Since VBA is an actual programming language, there isn't a reason *per se* you couldn't do this... but it just seems like a pretty big endeavor and as @terdon pointed out, there are easier ways to do what you want.

Comment: Hi @terdon and Doktoro, the reason it's a Word form is because I'm on a big account (client is State of CA) and my prime contractor along with everyone else on the project uses Microsoft Office to facilitate these kinds of info gathering activities. We also use SharePoint, but there's lots of red tape to go that route and I don't know anything about using a web form--from a tactical coding perspective... conceptually, I get it--to accomplish this.

Comment: yea it's all possible. sounds like a project ive been just assigned yesterday haha